# query collation on foreign language field in Latin table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, collation

I have a series of tables that each have a dedicated column to a foreign language. Languages vary from Japanese, Thai, English, Italian, French, more than 20 in all.

All of these tables are set up with Latin Case Insensitive collation. DB works fine.

But now I am trying to query against the specific foreign language column of each table. Lets take Japanese for starters. I'd like a foreign language user to enter foreign text and find the record based on the foreign language column.

```
  DECLARE @myVar nvarchar(max);

  SET @myVar =  'ｴﾝｼﾞﾝ ｽﾄｯﾌﾟ ﾘﾚｰ'      = 'Engine Stop Relay' in english

  Select *
  FROM tableJapanese
  WHERE langString = @myVar;
```

I have tried a multitude of collation combinations. I even copied the table and changed the collation of the column to Japanese_CI_AI and tried to query it that way.

None of these WHERE clauses work on either table/columm collation, when the column was Latin or Japanese...

```
WHERE lang_String collate Japanese_CI_AI = @myVar;
WHERE lang_String = @myVar collate Japanese_CI_AI;
WHERE lang_String collate Japanese_CI_AI = @myVar collate Japanese_CI_AI;

WHERE lang_String collate Japanese_CI_AI = @myVar;
WHERE lang_String = @myVar collate Japanese_CI_AI;
WHERE lang_String collate Japanese_CI_AI = @myVar collate Japanese_CI_AI;
```

I would like to leave the columns/database as Latin collation and code the queries for each language if possible.

This seems like one of those problems that if were a snake I'd been bitten already. Can anyone see what I am missing?

MSSQL Express 2008 R2

**SOLUTION**:

Add N in front of the field, it indicates unicode to SQL...

```
  Select *
  FROM tblLangJAP_test
  WHERE lang_String = N'ｴﾝｼﾞﾝ ｽﾄｯﾌﾟ ﾘﾚｰ';
```

Works flawlessly.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the datatype of the `lang_String` column?  A `varchar` or an `nvarchar`?

Comment: lang_String is an nvarchar(max) same as in my sample query

Comment: An exact match should always work, the collation should just add different cases and accents the the match list.  It would help if you set up an SQLFiddle.com example that replicates your problem?

Comment: I tried SQLFiddle.com but really it does not provide anything helpful. The string returned was all question marks '???? ????? ???'   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23d41/5/0

Comment: Well, maybe it displays the Japanese string wrong, but the `where` clause does match!  That was what you were looking for right?

Comment: In SQL ServerManagement Studio it does not even return the ?????.  I am looking to get the record results back from my database, what ever the changes are that I need to make. I am hoping someone out there is more familiar with COLLATION that can guide me to a solution.

Comment: Without a reproducible example of what exactly goes wrong, this is hard to answer even for the guy who wrote collate on the SQL Server team.  Best of luck tho!

Comment: Well, not to be rude to any one that reads this. I was provided the ever so humbling solution from a colleague. Add N in front of the string field, the orig post has been updated to show the solution. Thanks for the posts folks, it kept me looking.

Comment: Doh that's obvious in hindsight :)  Consider posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add N in front of the field, it indicates unicode to SQL...
  Select * 
  FROM tblLangJAP_test 
  WHERE lang_String = N'ｴﾝｼﾞﾝ ｽﾄｯﾌﾟ ﾘﾚｰ';

Works flawlessly.