# Foreign accent / Collation SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, collation

We are mapping and copying the database from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition (we don't have control) to SQL Server 2008 R2 (we do have control).

The data copying is done by the C# code with Oracle Client (ODAC). Everything works fine until we need to verify the copied data at SQL Server 2008 R2.

The problem lies with SQL Server 2008 R2.

With SQL Server Management Studio, I am able to see a record with field in foreign accent:

```
select * 
from EVENT_LOG 
where ID = 30268 and EVENT_DATETIME = '2014-9-24 13:10:31.000'
```

This query will return multiple records, I just show one record as

```
ID            | EVENT_DATETIME               | ........ | EVENT_DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
30268         |2014-9-24 13:10:31.0000000    | ........ | Les cibles XM Num et/ou les limites ont �t� automatiquement mises � jour.
```

The primary key of this table consists of `ID`, `EVENT_DATETIME` and `EVENT_DESCRIPTION`. Hence, it is necessary to include all 3 fields in the query to locate a unique record.

So a query will be like

```
select * 
from EVENT_LOG 
where ID = 30268 
  and EVENT_DATETIME = '2014-9-24 13:10:31.0000000' 
  and EVENT_DESCRIPTION = 'Les cibles XM Num et/ou les limites ont �t� automatiquement mises � jour.'
```

However, the above query will return nothing in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio. This is also the case, when I run the query in the C# code using Microsoft SQL CLIENT. I got no record returned. This column "EVENT_DESCRIPTION" needs to store all kinds of foreign accents, not limited to French.

The collation in SQL Server 2008 R2 is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I also tried a query

```
select * 
from EVENT_LOG 
where ID = 30268 
  and EVENT_DATETIME = '2014-9-24 13:10:31.0000000' 
  and EVENT_DESCRIPTION = N'Les cibles XM Num et/ou les limites ont �t� automatiquement mises � jour.'
```

as suggested by this link "[query collation on foreign language field in Latin table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676449/query-collation-on-foreign-language-field-in-latin-table)". It does not work yet.

EVENT_DESCRIPTION is "nvarchar(4000)"

Comment: What **datatype** is your `EVENT_DESCRIPTION` column in SQL Server?

Comment: EVENT_DESCRIPTION is "nvarchar(4000)"

Comment: You cannot possibly index a `nvarchar(4000)` column ..... an index in SQL Server can be an entry of a **maximum of 900 bytes** ....

Comment: We are mapping the database table in Oracle to SQL server. So it is true, we actually do not have EVENT_DESCRIPTION as part of the MS SQL server primary key. On the MS SQL server, we have created an primary key as identity and import the data from Oracle. However, Oracle does not have such "identity" key. But we need to verify the imported records in SQL server. So I have to run the query like that to MS SQL.